# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #119: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, inflate-exception

I have tried multiple solutions out there, if I remove code from the line `107` to `188` everything works ok and there is no error in inflation, but I am unable to pinpoint bug in that specific code.

Everything works ok in Android 8+ without removing any code but when I compile this in Android 6 it crashes on line 119.

**Layout file:**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        tools:context="com.jutt.professoryapp.view.fragments.LoginFragment">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivArabLogin"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_design_307"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_design_498"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_design_162"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:src="@drawable/arab_login_image"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/email_input_layout"
            style="@style/AppTextInputLayoutOutlined"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_design_100"
            android:hint="@string/email"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ivArabLogin">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/etEmail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:maxLength="@integer/maxLength_email" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/password_input_layout"
        style="@style/AppTextInputLayoutOutlined"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_design_100"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_design_36"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_design_100"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/email_input_layout">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/etPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        style="@style/AppButton.RoundCorners"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_design_140"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_design_36"
        android:text="@string/login"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/password_input_layout"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/password_input_layout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/password_input_layout" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btnLoginAsGuest"
        style="@style/AppButton.RoundCorners"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_design_140"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_design_36"
        android:text="@string/login_as_guest"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/btnLogin"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btnLogin"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnLogin" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/mbtn_ForgetPassword"
        style="@style/AppButton.TextButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/forget_password_q"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btnLogin"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnLogin" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/mbtn_signup"
        style="@style/AppButton.TextButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/btnLogin"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btnLogin"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mbtn_ForgetPassword" />
//////// Buggy Code /////////
    <View
        android:id="@+id/mtv_crossLine"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_design_52"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_design_52"
        android:background="@color/gray"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/mtv_or"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/btnLogin"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btnLogin"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/mtv_or" />

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/mtv_or"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:padding="@dimen/margin_design_15"
            android:text="@string/or"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle1"
            android:textColor="@color/primaryTextColor"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/btnLogin"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btnLogin"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mbtn_signup" />

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/mbtn_loginSocialLabel"
            style="@style/AppTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_design_30"
            android:text="@string/login_social_media_label"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/btnLogin"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btnLogin"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mtv_or" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ib_twitter_login"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_design_162"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_design_12"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_btn_rounded_corner_twitter"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/ib_google_login"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/mtv_or"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btnLogin"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mbtn_loginSocialLabel">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/twitter_bird_white"
                android:contentDescription="@string/login" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ib_google_login"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_design_162"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_design_12"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_btn_white_rounded_login"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/btnLogin"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/mtv_or"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mbtn_loginSocialLabel">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="@dimen/margin_design_19"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_google_g_icon"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:contentDescription="@string/login" />
    </LinearLayout>
//////// Buggy Code /////////
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

**dimen.xml**

```
.
.
<dimen name="margin_design_3">1dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_design_6">2dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_design_12">4dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_design_15">5dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_design_19">6dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_design_20">7dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_design_21">7dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_design_24">8dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_design_27">9dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_design_30">10dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_design_33">11dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_design_36">12dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_design_40">13dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_design_43">14dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_design_45">15dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_design_47">15dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_design_48">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_design_52">17dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_design_56">18dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_design_60">20dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_design_63">21dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_design_67">22dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_design_71">23dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_design_75">25dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_design_78">26dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_design_80">26dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_design_81">27dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_design_86">28dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_design_87">29dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_design_90">30dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_design_93">31dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_design_96">32dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_design_100">33dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_design_103">34dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_design_105">35dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_design_110">36dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_design_120">40dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_design_128">43dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_design_137">45dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_design_140">46dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_design_143">47dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_design_160">53dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_design_162">54dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_design_170">56dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_design_175">58dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_design_178">59dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_design_180">60dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_design_196">65dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_design_258">86dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_design_289">96dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_design_307">102dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_design_340">108dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_design_390">115dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_design_407">135dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_design_498">166dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_design_508">170dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_design_550">183dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_design_590">196dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_design_630">210dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_design_906">302dp</dimen>
.
.
```

**stack trace:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.jutt.professoryapp.internal/com.jutt.professoryapp.view.activities.LoginActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #119: Binary XML file line #119: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4156)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4258)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3361)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7237)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #119: Binary XML file line #119: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
        at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.inflate(DataBindingUtil.java:126)
        at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.inflate(DataBindingUtil.java:95)
        at com.jutt.professoryapp.view.fragments.LoginFragment.onCreateView(LoginFragment.kt:52)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2935)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:539)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:276)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:112)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1632)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:455)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2389)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2145)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2083)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1985)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:451)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onResume(FragmentActivity.java:414)
        at com.jutt.professoryapp.view.activities.LoginActivity.onResume(LoginActivity.kt:49)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1286)
        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6987)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4258) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3361) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7237) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #119: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:657)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
        at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.inflate(DataBindingUtil.java:126) 
        at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.inflate(DataBindingUtil.java:95) 
        at com.jutt.professoryapp.view.fragments.LoginFragment.onCreateView(LoginFragment.kt:52) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2935) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:539) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:276) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:112) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1632) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:455) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2389) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2145) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2083) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1985) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:451) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onResume(FragmentActivity.java:414) 
        at com.jutt.professoryapp.view.activities.LoginActivity.onResume(LoginActivity.kt:49) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1286) 
        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6987) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4145) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4258) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3361) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7237) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:631)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
        at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.inflate(DataBindingUtil.java:126) 
        at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.inflate(DataBindingUtil.java:95) 
        at com.jutt.professoryapp.view.fragments.LoginFragment.onCreateView(LoginFragment.kt:52) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2935) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:539) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:276) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:112) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1632) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:455) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2389) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2145) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2083) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1985) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:451) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onResume(FragmentActivity.java:414) 
        at com.jutt.professoryapp.view.activities.LoginActivity.onResume(LoginActivity.kt:49) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1286) 
        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6987) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4145) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4258) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3361) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7237) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
     Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=47; index=1576
        at android.content.res.StringBlock.get(StringBlock.java:65)
        at android.content.res.XmlBlock$Parser.getPooledString(XmlBlock.java:459)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.loadStringValueAt(Ty
```

**any help would be appreciated!!!**

Comment: Include stacktrace of the crash, and add the lines in concern in another code-block

Comment: added stack trace

Comment: What the base theme of your application in styles.xml?

Comment: app theme is `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar`

Comment: Does it work if you instead of `android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle1`, use `app:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle1`? I think the Android scope only works on latest Android versions. The app scope should work for all.

Comment: @Fred no it doesn't work gives error `AAPT: error: attribute textAppearance (aka com.jutt.professoryapp.internal:textAppearance) not found.`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @Fred for the hint in the comments problem was with `android:textAllCaps` which should be `app:textAllCaps` in MaterialTextView once I fixed that everything works ok.

```
<com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/mtv_or"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:padding="@dimen/margin_design_15"
            android:text="@string/or"
            android:textAllCaps="true" **<-- Problem**
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle1"
            android:textColor="@color/primaryTextColor"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/btnLogin"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btnLogin"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mbtn_signup" />
```